# Downloading files from the other side of a login

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

I need to use Python to download a large number of URLS, but they require a password to access them (similar to systems like cpanel, for example).

Is there a way I can do this, storing the cookie?

I'd like to use urllib2 if possible.

EDIT: To clarify, it's my website and I have the login details.

UPDATE:
OK I'm using this:

```
cj          = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener      = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data  =   urllib.urlencode({'login_name' : username, 'password' : password})
opener.open(loginURL, login_data)
productlist = opener.open(productURL)
print productlist.read()
```

But it just spits out the login page again. What isn't working?
(Variables are there, I just didn't show you what they are for security)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor`, like this:

```
import urllib2
from cookielib import CookieJar

cookiejar = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
cookieproc = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar)
opener.add_handler(cookieproc)
```

Then you just use `opener.open()` to access URLs, and cookies will automatically be saved and reused in future requests.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I give it the password on the first time round?

Comment: I believe there is a login form somewhere on the site, which posts to another page with the login details, just look at how the site works for login and use urllib to post on the right page with the right data. Your cookie will be automatically populated.

Comment: But how do I get the cookie from my browser?

Comment: If you want the cookie from your browser, you have to find the right file where the cookie is stored by your browser, and load it into your cookiejar.